# Deserialize xml which uses attribute name/value pairs

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

My application receives a constant stream of xml files which are more or less a direct copy of the database record

```
<record type="update">
    <field name="id">987654321</field>
    <field name="user_id">4321</field>
    <field name="updated">2011-11-24 13:43:23</field>
</record>
```

And I need to deserialize this into a class which provides nullable property's for all columns

```
class Record {
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
}
```

I just cant seem to work out a method of doing this without having to parse the xml file manually and switch on the field's `name` attribute to store the values.
Is their a way this can be achieved quickly using an XmlSerializer? And if not is their a more efficient way of parsing it manually?

Regards and thanks

---

My main problem is that the attribute `name` needs to have its value set to a property name and its value as the contents of a `<field>..</field>` element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**
*Edited the answer to reflect the best you can get with your current xml layout you will get an array of field objects with two properties, Name, eg ID, and Value, the text in the node*

You can create an Xml Definition class, pass this to an Xml Serializer and it will return you the object with the values of your xml intialised into it's properties.

So given the following definition file.

```
    [XmlTypeAttribute]
    [XmlRootAttribute("record")]
    public class RecordXmlConfiguration
    {

        [XmlElementAttribute("field")]
        public Field[] Fields { get; set; }


    }

    [XmlTypeAttribute]
    public class Field
    {
        [XmlAttributeAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Then when you have your xml you pass it to a method and it should return you an object of the type of your Xml defintiion class as so

```
    public static object Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        var deserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RecordXmlConfiguration));
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            return (RecordXmlConfiguration)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

It can be fiddly, but when its set up right it's saved me tonnes of time, as when your done with it you can also create a serialize method in the same maanner to return it to it's Xml form.

make sure to add references to your project to allow for these using statements

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
```

Comment: I've used XML serialization in the past, and it works like a charm. However, as a side note, I never figured out how to capture XML tag attributes.

Comment: @Bodyloss you can decorate it with a default value as follows `[XmlAttribute("IsAdmin"), DefaultValue(false)]` just change the default value as appropriate =)

Comment: @Xbones I've modified my answer somewhat The `AttributeAttribute` decorator should get the atribute than say a value in the tags

Comment: Damit, so close. Can't got it to print `<id>123456</id>` but not `<field name="id">123456</id>`

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you mean. With the nodes having the same tag of type `<Field>` The best in the above scenario is to have a decorator of type `[XmlElementAttribute("Field")]` over a property that is an IEnumerable of a class `Field` That you define with a name property

Comment: @bodyloss check the edited answer, it worked for me in a console app as the best you can get for your xml set up at the moment

Comment: Deserialize to a list of class `Field` (in the answer) and then convert it to the class `Record` in the question. Just need to add a `[XmlText] public string Content;` to the class `Field`.

Comment: @ErikH the `Value` property in the Field class represents your content property. Though I agree once Bodyloss has the XML Serialized they can convert it to a `Record` class to make it more usable with proper typed properties rather than all of them being strings.

Comment: This is perfect for handling the common pattern of XML "Extrinsic" fields

Comment: Tried with DataContractSerializer and couldn't find a way to automatic deserialize based on the attribute value. :-(